# Scrollable div, still scrolls with not much content

Tags: html, css

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/8d2nn0kL/1/)

I have an absolutely positioned container, inside is a div that scrolls, the problem is, when there is not enough content to scroll, the user can still scroll.

The cause seems to be the margin on the p tags, but this only has an effect when the parent is absolutely positioned (which it must be).

Does anyone have a solution to stop the overflow when there is not much content?

HTML:

```
<div id="container">
  <div id="container-scroller">
    <header>
      <h1>Title</h1>
    </header>
    <p>content</p>
    <p>content</p>
    <p>content</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#container{
  position: absolute;
  width: 50%;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  left: 50%;
}

#container-scroller{
  max-width: 600px;
  margin: auto;
  position: relative;
  min-height: 100%;
```

}

EDIT

Some have suggested removing the min height of 100% - I need to keep this in.

Comment: It's the `min-height: 100%;`. Remove it.

Answer (score 0):

<del>You have to remove the `min-height: 100%;`.</del>

EDIT:

It's a bit "hacky" but you could add a negative top margin:

```css
#container {
  position: absolute;
  width: 50%;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  left: 50%;
}
#container-scroller {
  max-width: 600px;
  margin: auto;
  position: relative;
  min-height: 100%;
  margin-top: -21px;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div id="container-scroller">
    <header>
      <h1>Title</h1>
    </header>
    <p>content</p>
    <p>content</p>
    <p>content</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

The offset comes from the scrollbar.

Comment: Thanks but I need the scroller to be 100% height

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `margin-bottom: 2em;` on your header tag. If you need the spacing, try using padding instead.

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to use absolute and relative positioning to center your content. If you remove your position CSS from both divs, and make their height 100%, your problem will be resolved. You can then center align your scroller div by adding `text-align: center` to your container.

[JS Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/8d2nn0kL/4/)

```
#container{
  /*position: absolute;
  width: 50%;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  left: 50%;*/
  height: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}

#container-scroller{
  max-width: 600px;
  margin: auto;
  /*position: relative;*/
  min-height: 100%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add overflow hidden to the scrolled container and overflow auto to the absolute positioned parent container:

```css
#container {
    position: absolute;
    width: 50%;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
    left: 50%;
    overflow: auto;
}
#container-scroller {
    max-width: 600px;
    margin: auto;
    position: relative;
    min-height: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div id="container-scroller">
    <header>
      <h1>Title</h1>
    </header>
    <p>content</p>
    <p>content</p>
    <p>content</p>
  </div>
</div>
```